# .AddNew Record with Multiselect combobox

Tags: vba, ms-access

I have a table where the user can store file directories of images, and can relate these images to a certain item by adding the items to a 'relatesTo' field, which is a multiselect lookup field within the table. However for instance if I want to automate the adding of these images to a specific item...

```
Dim fd As FileDialog
Dim FileChosen As Integer
Dim FileName As String
Dim i As Integer

Set fd = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFilePicker)
    fd.InitialFileName = Application.CurrentProject.Path
    fd.InitialView = msoFileDialogViewList
    fd.AllowMultiSelect = True

FileChosen = fd.Show

If FileChosen = -1 Then

    Dim rst As DAO.Recordset
    Set rst = CurrentDb.OpenRecordset("ManufacturingImages", dbOpenDynaset)

    For i = 1 To fd.SelectedItems.Count
        With rst
            .AddNew
                !imagePath = fd.SelectedItems(i)
                !dateTaken = Date
                !relatesTo = 29 ' Will change dependant upon the selection
            .Update
        End With
    Next i

    rst.Close
    Set rst = Nothing

End If
```

The problem here is due to 'relatesTo being a multiselect field the following code results in the error; 64224: Method 'Collect' of object 'Recordset2' failed.

I am on the right lines of saying that I need to specify 'relatesTo' as a separate recordset, or am I just getting the syntax wrong? I have tried doing something like this but have had no success. Also
'relatesTo' just refers to the autoID of items within a table called products.

Moreover, I know an easy work around for this would be to have a separate table which would act as this combobox where I would have many to many relationship but I would like to understand how I can get this to work.

Comment: Indeed, it's a recordset within a recordset of type `Recordset2`. But do yourself a favor and scrap it, it will only cause trouble. Store directly the id.

Comment: What is the major issue with using multiselect values? I wouldnt go this way with substantial data, however for this scenario this works rather well, as the user can easily see at a glance what the images relates to, as for example, one image may contain several products

Comment: See this http://access.mvps.org/access/lookupfields.htm

Comment: A lookup field is not always a multi-value field. However, I recommend to never use multi-value field and never build lookup in table. I never have.

Comment: Drawbacks to MVF field are: 1) special coding required to programmatically manipulate; 2) not migratable to other db platforms; 3) pointer to records in hidden dependent table so table relationship is not apparent; 4) requires lookup field in table (built either by Lookup wizard or manually for a regular text/number field). There may be more but if you are not put off by these attributes, have at it.